# Win32_EncryptableVolume Device loop in C#

Tags: c#, loops, invoke, usb-drive

I'm trying to build a loop for each device that may be connected to a Win7 and up machine using BitLocker. It hasn't been an issue in the past since we've been using TPMs, but now we're trying USB keys to reduce costs. My old code only showed the last devices encryption status which ended up being the USB drive. So I'd like to create a loop that lists each drive and it's encryption status.

My goal is to create an array with each drives status in it. The problem I'm running in to is identifying how many items are actually found as a result of searcher.Get() (which I believe should be the encrArr array below), so I'm going with 2 for now for the hard drive and USB drive.

The code below doesn't show any errors while writing it, but it crashes when I try to run it ("Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.").

```
public string[] getBitLockerArr()
{
    string[] encrArr = new string[2];
    encrArr[0] = "Protection Off, Fully Decrypted, 0% encrypted";
    encrArr[1] = "Protection Off, Fully Decrypted, 0% encrypted";

    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new
        ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\cimv2\\Security\\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption", "SELECT * FROM Win32_EncryptableVolume");    
    int i = 0;

    foreach (ManagementObject wmi in searcher.Get())
    {
        try
        {
            string[] bitLockerArr = new string[3];
            bitLockerArr[0] = "Unknown";
            bitLockerArr[1] = "Unknown";
            bitLockerArr[2] = "Unknown";

            StringBuilder bitLocker = new StringBuilder();

            ManagementObject classInstance =
                new ManagementObject("root\\cimv2\\Security\\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption", "Win32_EncryptableVolume.DeviceID='" + wmi["DeviceID"] + "'", null);

            ManagementBaseObject statProtection = classInstance.InvokeMethod("GetProtectionStatus", null, null);
            ManagementBaseObject statConversion = classInstance.InvokeMethod("GetConversionStatus", null, null);

            if (statProtection["ProtectionStatus"] != null) { bitLockerArr[0] = statProtection["ProtectionStatus"].ToString(); }
            if (statConversion["ConversionStatus"] != null) { bitLockerArr[1] = statConversion["ConversionStatus"].ToString(); }
            if (statConversion["EncryptionPercentage"] != null) { bitLockerArr[2] = statConversion["EncryptionPercentage"].ToString(); }

            // BitLocker Protection Status
            string blProtStat = bitLockerArr[0];
            if (blProtStat == "0") { blProtStat = "Protection Off"; }
            else if (blProtStat == "1") { blProtStat = "Protection On"; }

            // BitLocker Conversion Statuses
            string blConvStat = bitLockerArr[1];
            if (blConvStat == "0") { blConvStat = ", Fully Decrypted"; }
            else if (blConvStat == "1") { blConvStat = ", Fully Encrypted"; }
            else if (blConvStat == "2") { blConvStat = ", Encryption In Progress"; }
            else if (blConvStat == "3") { blConvStat = ", Decryption In Progress"; }
            else if (blConvStat == "4") { blConvStat = ", Encryption Paused"; }
            else if (blConvStat == "5") { blConvStat = ", Decryption Paused"; }

            // BitLocker Encryption Status
            string blEncStat = ", " + bitLockerArr[2] + "% encrypted";

            encrArr[i] = wmi["DriveLetter"] + " " + blProtStat + blConvStat + blEncStat + ", " + wmi["DeviceID"];
            i = i + 1;
        }
        catch { }
    }

    return encrArr;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't getting any errors when running in debug, so I compiled it and got the error line. It was actually on the form side because I forgot to comment out the call to the original array. It was looking for three things, but only had 2 and errored out.

I'm still wondering how to set the size of the bitLockerArr array to the number of items returned by the query?